# Quarkus with JPA / Hibernate Session causes ContextNotActiveException in JMS Threads

Tags: jpa, jms, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I try to use a Panache Repository from a thread, which is not "managed" by Quarkus (because we use ActiveMQ 5 JmsListeners where the `javax.jms.MessageConsumer` runs in its own thread pool). It's implemented like this snippet:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConsumer implements javax.jms.MessageListener {

    @Inject
    javax.jms.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    
    @Inject
    MyPanacheRepository repository;
    
    private Session session;
    
    public void init(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
        if (this.connectionFactory != null) {
            try {
                Connection connection = this.connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();
                this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Topic topic = session.createTopic(...);
                MessageConsumer consumer = this.session.createConsumer(...);
                consumer.setMessageListener(this);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        if (this.session != null) {
            try {
                this.session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        Job job = this.repository.findById(message.getLongProperty("jobId"));
    }

}
```

When the `onMessage()` method receives a message I get following exception:

```
ERROR [MyConsumer] (ActiveMQ Session Task-3)  javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: Cannot use the EntityManager/Session because neither a transaction nor a CDI request context is active. Consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate a transaction, or @ActivateRequestContext if you have valid reasons not to use transactions.
  at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:106)
  at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.find(TransactionScopedSession.java:173)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.find(SessionLazyDelegator.java:650)
  at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.find(Unknown Source)
  at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.findById(AbstractJpaOperations.java:179)
  at MyPanacheRepository.findById(MyPanacheRepository.java)
```

So the `MyPanacheRepository` does not find a way to aquire a Hibernate Session running in the thread `ActiveMQ Session Task-3`.

What might be the best solution to come address this? I can solve this problem by adding a `UserTransaction.begin()` call around the `findById(....)`, but I dont really need a transaction to just read data!?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had seen this earlier for you.

The issue is when you attempt to open a connection to the database the request context is not active yet because the application hasn't finished starting.

This line:

```java
public void init(@Observes StartupEvent event) {}
```

will make your init function run before the Quarkus application has finished all of its startup tasks, one of these being establishing a request context with the database.

In order to resolve your issue, you can slap this annotation on your init method, to tell it to fire up the database request context prior to running your init method.

```java
import jakarta.enterprise.context.control.ActivateRequestContext;
        
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyConsumer implements javax.jms.MessageListener {
    
    @ActivateRequestContext
    public void init(@Observes StartupEvent event) {}
}
```

If the onMessage() method still has the same issue you can give it the same annotation and that should solve your problem, but I think just annotating the init method should suffice.

Comment: In my case I was running Quarkus command mode application.  Adding `@ActivateRequestContext` on `run` method on `QuarkusApplication` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The logs indicate a mix of javax.* and jakarta.* frameworks. That is serious use-at-your-own-risk. You should confirm alignment with one or the other.

Note: activemq-client-jakarta 5.18.2 is available for jakarta-based messaging

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even see the mix and match in my response.